# Baffled by Multi-part identifier cannot be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a linked server to run a bunch of complicated queries. I had an issue I tracked down and simplified for testing.  The first 2 queries below work, but the third does not.

```
select top 10 AccountNumber
FROM S900PVXBIDWS01.FinancialEDW.MBFI.Dim_Account

select top 10 A.AccountNumber
FROM S900PVXBIDWS01.FinancialEDW.MBFI.Dim_Account A

select top 10 S900PVXBIDWS01.FinancialEDW.MBFI.Dim_Account.AccountNumber
FROM S900PVXBIDWS01.FinancialEDW.MBFI.Dim_Account
```

I need to use the last version for reasons I won't go into (lots of limitations).  Why won't it work when it clearly should?

The max for length identifiers is 128 I thought and I am under that. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I'm so intrigued as to why you cannot use the 2nd option.

Comment: Does it work if you put brackets around the server name?

Comment: I can't use the second option because this is a part of a group of a series of QA testing queries that pull the columns and tables from a database and dynamically creates testing queries.   This query doesn't work when run regularly (not with EXEC). The query is much simplified (it originally had 7 joins).

Comment: It doesn't work with brackets around the server.  I'll add I've run hundreds of queries on this table (and others in the database) without incident.

Comment: Column references don't use four-part naming (which would then be five parts).  Just use `Dim_Account.AccountNumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column references don't use four-part naming (which would then be five parts). Just use `Dim_Account.AccountNumber`, that should work fine.

Comment: Thanks.  I did just read that on another thread.  It does work just using the table name.